# Couting or integrating multivariate Gaussian probabilities on opposite side of non-linear decision line

Tags: machine-learning

So I have something that looks like the following:
[image: pdf plot with decision line]

However, I am having real trouble integrating the data on the other side of this decision line to get my errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, given analytic form of the decision boundary you could compute the integrals exactly. However, why not use monte carlo which is fast, simple and generic (will work for any distributions and decision boundaries). All you have to do is repeatedly sample from your gaussians, check if the sampled point is on the correct side (N_c) or incorrect (N_i) and in the limit you will get your integrals from

```
INTEGRAL_of_distributions_being_on_correct_side ~ N_c / (N_c + N_i)
INTEGRAL_of_distributions_being_on_incorrect_side ~ N_i / (N_c + N_i)
```

thus in pseudo code:

```
N_c = 0
N_i = 0

for i=1 to N do
   y ~ P({-, +}) # sample distribution
   x ~ P(X|y) # sample point from given class
   if side_of_decision(x) == y then
     N_c += 1
   else
     N_i += 1
   end
end

return N_c, N_i
```

In your case `P({-, +})` is probably just 50-50 chance and `P(X|-)` and `P(X|+)` are your two Gaussians.

Comment: very elegant solution to use MC to solve this, but in the end, I used F3 = F1 -F2 signed and i queried each points index into F3 to see if they were +/-